# How can I write an equation in the label section?

Tags: equations, labels

**Code:**

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{Images/Co2EOR.JPG}
\caption{.....}  }
\label{Cross-section  $$\textrm{CO}_{2}$$ EOR}
\end{figure}
```

**Error Message:**

> "Missing \endcsname inserted.
>
> \protect  l.191 ...ction $\textrm  {CO}_{2}$ EOR}{{5.1}{35}}
>
> ```
>                                                The control sequence marked <to be read again> should not appear between \csname
> ```
>
> and \endcsname."

Comment: label is not the caption ... but a way to refer to the figure by using \`ref` command ... So, a label like `cc-Co-2` should be enough to be used.

Answer (score 5):

Labels are only for internal use, they won't be displayed. You should remove all special characters like math things or spaces.

This will work:

```
\label{Cross-section-CO2-EOR}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping Maeve  :)